# Count the number of consecutive results in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to find how many times a consecutive specific result happens:

```
     Date                         Car         Result
2021-10-07 16:33:44.270      |   Toyota    |   PASS
2021-10-07 18:35:08.073      |   Ford      |   PASS
2021-10-07 18:39:31.497      |   Jeep      |   FAIL
2021-10-07 21:30:46.150      |   Jeep      |   FAIL
2021-10-08 03:38:55.370      |   Toyota    |   FAIL
2021-10-08 06:43:07.597      |   Ford      |   PASS
2021-10-08 07:10:22.897      |   Toyota    |   FAIL
2021-10-08 07:39:56.810      |   Jeep      |   PASS
2021-10-08 10:45:39.260      |   Toyota    |   PASS
2021-10-08 11:29:45.123      |   Ford      |   FAIL
```

I want to increase the number of consecutive failures when a FAIL result appears, and reset to 0 when a PASS result is achieved:

```
     Date                         Car         Failures
2021-10-07 16:33:44.270      |   Toyota    |   0
2021-10-07 18:35:08.073      |   Ford      |   0
2021-10-07 18:39:31.497      |   Jeep      |   1
2021-10-07 21:30:46.150      |   Jeep      |   2
2021-10-08 03:38:55.370      |   Toyota    |   1
2021-10-08 06:43:07.597      |   Ford      |   0
2021-10-08 07:10:22.897      |   Toyota    |   2
2021-10-08 07:39:56.810      |   Jeep      |   0
2021-10-08 10:45:39.260      |   Toyota    |   0
2021-10-08 11:29:45.123      |   Ford      |   1
```

Can anybody help me to find the right (T)SQL query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a pretty one, but I believe it satisfies your conditions as well as produces the desired result set when running using only your sample data.

I added some extra edge cases to demonstrate that it is working correctly.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (
    Date datetime
    ,Car varchar(50)
    ,Result varchar(4)
);
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES
('2021-10-07 16:33:44.270','Toyota','PASS')
,('2021-10-07 18:35:08.073','Ford','PASS')
,('2021-10-07 18:39:31.497','Jeep','FAIL')
,('2021-10-07 21:30:46.150','Jeep','FAIL')
,('2021-10-08 03:38:55.370','Toyota','FAIL')
,('2021-10-08 06:43:07.597','Ford','PASS')
,('2021-10-08 07:10:22.897','Toyota','FAIL')
,('2021-10-08 07:39:56.810','Jeep','PASS')
,('2021-10-08 10:45:39.260','Toyota','PASS')
,('2021-10-08 11:29:45.123','Ford','FAIL')
,('2021-10-09 18:39:31.497','Jeep','FAIL')
,('2021-10-09 21:30:46.150','Jeep','FAIL')
,('2021-10-10 18:39:31.497','Jeep','PASS')
,('2021-10-10 21:30:46.150','Jeep','FAIL')
,('2021-10-10 10:45:39.260','Toyota','FAIL');

SELECT 
    pass_grouping.Date 
    ,pass_grouping.Car 
    /*now perform final sum of your counter for consecutive failures (AKA anything other than 'PASS')*/
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN pass_grouping.Result = 'PASS' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY pass_grouping.Car,pass_grouping.PassGrouperId ORDER BY pass_grouping.Date) AS Failures    
FROM 
    /*generate a PassGrouperId to indicate a group of rows in which where there was no 'PASS' ocurrence (which would be indicated by incremented the value of pass_counter.PassOcurrenceRunningTotal).*/
    /*The first row of each PassGrouperId group indicates where we need to reset the value of our final column 'Failures'. So we can partition outer query on that value.*/
    (SELECT 
        pass_counter.Date 
        ,pass_counter.Car 
        ,pass_counter.Result
        ,RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY pass_counter.Car ORDER BY pass_counter.PassOcurrenceRunningTotal) AS PassGrouperId
    FROM 
        /*create indicator that tracks 'PASS' Result ocurrence chronologically (using Date column) per each Car value*/ 
        (SELECT 
            tbl.Date 
            ,tbl.Car 
            ,tbl.Result
            ,SUM(CASE WHEN tbl.Result = 'PASS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY Car ORDER BY Date) AS PassOcurrenceRunningTotal
        FROM 
            @Table AS tbl) AS pass_counter) AS pass_grouping 
ORDER BY 
    pass_grouping.Date;
```

Comment: Nice.  This was the direction I was moving towards after your comment and re-evaluating my answer.  Like you mentioned here find that passgroup based on the change which I totally overlooked.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT: My answer here is wrong because when the values in Result switch back to PASS or FAIL (according to the ordering in the ROW_NUMBER() OVER() clause), the numbering continues where it left off rather than resetting again to 1.**

You can accomplish this with [ROW_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and some `CASE` logic like so:

```sql
-- Assuming the example data you posted is in a temp table named #TBL
WITH ResultData AS (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER
        (
            -- Reset the count whenever the car or result changes
            PARTITION BY
                Car,
                Result
            -- Order first by car, and then by date so that the car won't change until we're done with it
            ORDER BY
                Car,
                Date
        )
        AS ResultCount
    FROM #TBL
)
SELECT Date, Car,
CASE WHEN Result = 'PASS' THEN 0 ELSE ResultCount END AS Failures
FROM ResultData
ORDER BY Date;
```

This yields the result example you posted.  If you want to build out the temp table and try it for yourself, then add these statements **before** the above query:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #TBL
(
    Date datetime,
    Car nvarchar(50),
    Result nvarchar(4)
);

INSERT INTO #TBL VALUES
( '2021-10-07 16:33:44.270','Toyota','PASS' ),
( '2021-10-07 18:35:08.073','Ford','PASS' ),
( '2021-10-07 18:39:31.497','Jeep','FAIL' ),
( '2021-10-07 21:30:46.150','Jeep','FAIL' ),
( '2021-10-08 03:38:55.370','Toyota','FAIL' ),
( '2021-10-08 06:43:07.597','Ford','PASS' ),
( '2021-10-08 07:10:22.897','Toyota','FAIL' ),
( '2021-10-08 07:39:56.810','Jeep','PASS' ),
( '2021-10-08 10:45:39.260','Toyota','PASS' ),
( '2021-10-08 11:29:45.123','Ford','FAIL' );
```

(Make sure you include the `;` at the end of the `INSERT` statement, otherwise it will choke on the `WITH` that starts the query.)

Comment: This is a hacky way to produce the requested result set, but I would not say that it satisfies OP's requested logic. For example, adding more data like `('2021-10-09 18:39:31.497','Jeep','FAIL'),('2021-10-09 21:30:46.150','Jeep','FAIL')` would then yield values of 3 and 4 (respectively) in the `Failures` column instead of 1 and 2. Your example does not actually `reset to 0 when a PASS result is achieved` as requested. In your example you are essentially just hiding this fact with a `CASE` statement

Comment: @trenton-ftw I concede, it does not behave the way I expected, and I didn't notice because it just happened to work out to the desired result using only the OP's example data.